# FacesComponent scope

Tags: jsf-2, myfaces, composite-component

**What scope has a FacesComponent??.**

Can i set something like ViewScope? SessionScope?

```
@FacesComponent(value="myComponent")
  public class MyComponent extends UINamingContainer  {
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. It makes design technically also no sense.

If you want to store some data in a certain scope, just explicitly store them in the desired scope yourself in one of the component's methods. The session scope for example is as a `Map` available by `ExternalContext#getSessionMap()`.

Comment: OK, thanks, can you help me with this please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11640049